# implement ProgressDialog with Gauge

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython

hello I want to implement my own ProgressDialog with a Gauge. I want to display the elapsed time.

Another thing. Is it possible to modify the Loader so that it faces round trips instead of going round in circles?

with`Python 3.5.2`

```
import wx
import time
class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kw)       
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer)
        self.gspeed = 10
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.timer.Start(self.gspeed)        
        self.star = True       
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        """ GUI
        """
        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)      
        self.btn1 = wx.Button(pnl, wx.ID_OK)
        self.btn2 = wx.Button(pnl, wx.ID_STOP)
        self.text = wx.StaticText(pnl)
        self.count = wx.StaticText(pnl)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOk, self.btn1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStop, self.btn2)
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(pnl, size=(250, -1), style = wx.GA_HORIZONTAL)
        hbox1.Add(self.gauge, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)        
        hbox2.Add(self.btn1, proportion=1, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=10)
        hbox2.Add(self.btn2, proportion=1)
        hbox3.Add(self.text, proportion=1, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=50)
        hbox3.Add(self.count, proportion=1)
        vbox.Add((0, 30))
        vbox.Add(hbox1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        vbox.Add((0, 20))
        vbox.Add(hbox2, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        vbox.Add(hbox3, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        pnl.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.SetTimeLabel()        
        self.SetTitle('SDA')
        self.Centre()        
    def OnOk(self, e):        
        self.text.SetLabel('Elapsed time')
        self.count.SetLabel("0")

    def OnStop(self, e):
        self.timer.Stop()
        self.text.SetLabel('Task Interrupted')
    def OnTimer(self, e):
        self.gauge.Pulse()        
    def SetTimeLabel(self):
        self.text.SetLabel('Task')        
def main():
    app = wx.App()
    ex = Example(None)
    ex.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

my priority is the time elapsed. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the elapsed time subtract the start time from the current time. I've added the method `get_elapsed_time` to your example below.

```
import wx
import time


class Example(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.OnTimer)
        self.gspeed = 10
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.timer.Start(self.gspeed)
        self.star = True

        self.start_time = time.time()

        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        """ GUI
        """
        pnl = wx.Panel(self)
        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        hbox1 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox3 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        self.btn1 = wx.Button(pnl, wx.ID_OK)
        self.btn2 = wx.Button(pnl, wx.ID_STOP)
        self.text = wx.StaticText(pnl)
        # self.count = wx.StaticText(pnl)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnOk, self.btn1)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnStop, self.btn2)
        self.gauge = wx.Gauge(pnl, size=(250, -1), style=wx.GA_HORIZONTAL)
        hbox1.Add(self.gauge, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        hbox2.Add(self.btn1, proportion=1, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=10)
        hbox2.Add(self.btn2, proportion=1)
        hbox3.Add(self.text, proportion=1, flag=wx.RIGHT, border=50)
        # hbox3.Add(self.count, proportion=1)
        vbox.Add((0, 30))
        vbox.Add(hbox1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        vbox.Add((0, 20))
        vbox.Add(hbox2, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        vbox.Add(hbox3, proportion=1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        pnl.SetSizer(vbox)
        self.SetTimeLabel()
        self.SetTitle('SDA')
        self.Centre()

        self.Layout()

    def OnOk(self, e):
        self.SetTimeLabel()
        # self.count.SetLabel("0")

    def OnStop(self, e):
        self.timer.Stop()
        self.text.SetLabel('Task Interrupted')

    def OnTimer(self, e):
        self.gauge.Pulse()
        self.SetTimeLabel()

    def get_elapsed_time(self):
        return round(time.time() - self.start_time, 1)

    def SetTimeLabel(self):
        self.text.SetLabel("{elapsed} seconds elapsed".format(elapsed=self.get_elapsed_time()))


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    ex = Example(None)
    ex.Show()
    app.MainLoop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: @LandryEngolo you're welcome, feel free to give it an upvote if it helped you ;)